# Is Clock.exe all you get from Tick_Tock?

Tags: hacknet

I finally get to the end(?) of the hidden mission that starts with an email to dlocke. But I've only gained a file called `Clock.exe`,after deciphering it. Is that all? A program of a clock?

Comment: Pretty cool, right? If you feel like you need more, check the `/home` folder and download some IRC logs or creative writing assignments. `CreativeWritingAssignment_2.doc` was pretty cool, and I let the trace finish to complete a download of `Assignment4`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have hacknet on steam it gives you an achievement. Otherwise it's a clock..